# Android studio Error when updating to 3.4

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.4

I want to update my android studio version to 3.4 from my current one (3.3.2).

But when I choose :

`Help > Check for updates > Update and Restart`

It looks like it is updating, after a few seconds I am getting this error :

```
Connection Error
        Failed to prepare an update:
        Temp directory inside installation: C:\Users\Tamir\.AndroidStudio3.3\system\tmp\patch-update
        Open download page.
```

**The "Open download page" link just sends me to [downloading android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/?utm_source=android-studio)**

I really don't want to download android studio all over again, any ideas why I am getting this error?

**Note-** I have checked some stack overflow threads before asking this, the best thing I found was to `Invalidate Caches/Restart` but this did not fix the error.

Comment: Did you check to have sufficient space on your C disk to contain the installation file?

Comment: yes, the download size os about 0.5 gigabyte if I remember correctly and I have about 10 gigabytes available

Comment: Please don't tag with Android when your question is about the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to [download Android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) 3.4 all over again.

The good thing is that when downloading a new version, if you already had another version of an android studio at the installation you will receive an option to delete the old version.

So if any of you are getting the same error don't worry about downloading android studio again, the installation is really fast.