# Android studio shows IDE error when updated from 3.2 to 3.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

As i was working on a project,i updated my android studio from 3.2 to 3.4.1.after updating as i want to add a new activity ,the android studio shows an error of IDE error when i add new activity.
as i tried to clean and rebuild the project the issue does not resolved

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I had a problem too upgrading android studio. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772185/android-studio-error-when-updating-to-3-4) .

Comment: IDE error -p_anantha