# Unable to update Android Studio to 3.4.1

Tags: android-studio

While I am trying to update android studio to 3.4.1 (Latest Stable Version) its failed with some error.

Error: some conflicts were found in the installation area that doesn't have a solution.
[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXyye.png)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772185/android-studio-error-when-updating-to-3-4)

Comment: @TamirAbutbul this does not relate to my problem

Comment: @Zoe Just to save you time. I suggest you delete the current version you have at the moment and redownload the latest version and install it with administrative privileges. One of the applications on your machine either your antivirus has locked access to the files it needs to access to update

Comment: @George I'm not the asker btw

Comment: @Zoe sorry my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way you install the new version is:

1. Uninstall completely the actual version
2. Download the new version.
3. Install the new version.

Comment: is it gonna remove all my SDK, emulator and configuration file?

Comment: the configuration files not but all other yes, be careful in the installation instruction.