# Where did the "Profile or Debug APK..." option disappear to in Android Studio 3.4.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, profile

Android Studio used to have the option to debug existing APKs from the **File->Profile** or **Debug APK**. I have used it in Android Studio version 3.4. Now at version 3.4.1, I cannot find it.

Does anyone know if the option was removed from Android Studio or where can I find it?

Comment: Are you running macOS?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as OP and I'm on macOS. The Profile or Debug APK is also missing from the start window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJzfj.png

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling android studio, but it is still missing

Comment: @MaximePeloquin I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue and here's how I solved it.

I had disabled APK and NDK support in hopes that it would speed up my IDE. I forgot to turn them back on. So I went into `Preferences > Plugins` and if you don't have them installed, install Android NDK and Android APK support. If you already have them installed, tick `Android APK Support` and it will prompt you to enable `Android NDK Support` if you don't have it enabled already.

Comment: You stole my answer !

Comment: @HartWoom No I didn't... You said "Android SDK Support" not "Android APK Support" or "Android NDK Support".

Answer (score 1):

Since Android Studio menu can be customize, by some way the option has been removed from your toolbar. To add it again go in **File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Menus and Toolbar**

From here open the **Main menu -> File -> File Open Actions** folders.

Select the **Open** line, then click on the plus sign on top of the window next to the search bar. Click **Add Action...** and search for **Profile or Debug APK...** options.

Apply and you're good to go !

### **Edit**

After some exchanges in the comments we fixed the issue another way.

You have to go into **Settings -> Plugins** first. Check if you have the plugin **Android APK Support** activated/installed. If not then install/activate it.

And now you're really good to go !

Comment: For me `Profile or Debug APK...` option is already in the Menus and Toolbar options, but it is not showing in the File menu

Comment: @MaximePeloquin Have you tried removing and adding it again ? I haven't had this issue, so I'm going blind here.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. The profil or debug APK is also missing from the Android Studio start page https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJzfj.png

Comment: For me It wasn't there initially but when I tried to add it nothing happened.

Comment: @MaximePeloquin search in the plugins if you have the **Android APK Support** plugin enabled. If not try enabling it and restart android studio.

Comment: That was it for me @HartWoom! If you modify your answer to include this, I'll award you the bounty. Thanks a lot for checking into this, I've been having this issue for a long time now

Comment: @MaximePeloquin I've edited the question. Glad I could help ! Cheers from France ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's weird because I am using android studio 3.4.1 and its there:

[image]

When I had problems after updating android studio all I did was to re-install it and my problems got fixed.

Also, you should know that downloading another version of Android studio is really user-friendly, check [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772185/android-studio-error-when-updating-to-3-4) about it.

Comment: I reinstalled Android Studio 3.4.1 (Mac) and I still don't have the "Profile or Debug APK..." option. [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtfidkexxt5ikgp/Screenshot%202019-06-30%2011.24.34.png?dl=0)