# How to fix " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/r8/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultiset" error

Tags: android, android-studio, build

After upgrading my android studio and gradle plugin to the latest version, i tried to build my project apk  but i got this error  "Cause: com/android/tools/r8/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultiset", i'm lost and couldn't find anything related to "ImmutableMultiset" on google search. Can anyone help me out Please?

I have tried Invalidate caches, yet not solved..

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.talkbiz.naijaexamspreparations"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            pseudoLocalesEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.github.antonKozyriatskyi:CircularProgressIndicator:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.maltaisn:calcdialog:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'de.psdev.formvalidations:formvalidations:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:5.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I just delete and reinstall android studio if I can't fix my problem instead of looking for a solution for days. as mentioned in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772185/android-studio-error-when-updating-to-3-4) it won't take too long.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul Haaa, delete and reinstall??

Comment: can you add your build.gradle, i think you have to add guava dependency

Comment: @Ahmed.ess build.gradle project or module ?

Comment: @Ahmed.ess i have added my build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with the below steps:

1. Go to "C:\Users{username}.gradle\caches" folder
2. And delete all the files.
3. Then try